# Как мне активировать кнопку находящуюся позади QWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Я хочу нажать на `radio_1`, `radio_2`, `radio_3`, но при этом чтобы внешний вид оставался тем же самым.

Писать `radio_1.setStyleSheet('   background:rgba(200, 0, 0, 255)')` мне не подходит.

Есть ли в `PyQt` какая-нибудь команда для того, что бы сделать `QWidget` прозрачным для действий мыши.

Мой код

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)

        radio_1 = QRadioButton()
        radio_1.setStyleSheet(' background:  blue')
        lay.addWidget(radio_1)

        radio_2 = QRadioButton()
        radio_2.setStyleSheet(' background:  red')
        lay.addWidget(radio_2)


        radio_3 = QRadioButton()
        radio_3.setStyleSheet(' background:  green')
        lay.addWidget(radio_3)

        buttonGroup = QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.onButtonClicked)   #(int id)
        buttonGroup.addButton(radio_1, 1)
        buttonGroup.addButton(radio_2, 2)
        buttonGroup.addButton(radio_3, 3)

        block = QWidget(self)
        block.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))
        block.setStyleSheet(' background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 130)')

        lay_2 = QVBoxLayout(block)

        Label = QLabel()
        Label.setText('TEXT')
        Label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        lay_2.addWidget(Label)

        radio_4 = QRadioButton()
        radio_4.setStyleSheet(' background:  yellow')

        lay_2.addWidget(radio_4)

        buttonGroup.addButton(radio_4, 4)

    def onButtonClicked(self, id):
        print(id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: что значит "прозрачным"? опишите что конкретно хотите. может быть даже с картинками. Сейчас вопрос звучит как "я хочу чтобы было как я хочу, но происходит по другому"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))

        self.x1r1, self.x2r1, self.y1r1, self.y2r1 = ..., ..., ..., ...            # +++
        self.x1r2, self.x2r2, self.y1r2, self.y2r2 = ..., ..., ..., ...
        self.x1r3, self.x2r3, self.y1r3, self.y2r3 = ..., ..., ..., ...

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.radio_1 = QRadioButton()                                 # всем radio_x  self
        self.radio_1.setStyleSheet(' background:  blue')
        lay.addWidget(self.radio_1)

        self.radio_2 = QRadioButton()
        self.radio_2.setStyleSheet(' background:  red')
        lay.addWidget(self.radio_2)

        self.radio_3 = QRadioButton()
        self.radio_3.setStyleSheet(' background:  green')
        lay.addWidget(self.radio_3)

        buttonGroup = QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.onButtonClicked)   #(int id)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.radio_1, 1)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.radio_2, 2)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.radio_3, 3)

        block = QWidget(self)
        block.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))
        block.setStyleSheet(' background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 130)')

        lay_2 = QVBoxLayout(block)

        Label = QLabel()
        Label.setText('TEXT')
        Label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        lay_2.addWidget(Label)

        radio_4 = QRadioButton()
        radio_4.setStyleSheet(' background:  yellow')

        lay_2.addWidget(radio_4)

        buttonGroup.addButton(radio_4, 4)

    def onButtonClicked(self, id):
        print(id)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):                                        # +++
        g1 = self.radio_1.geometry()
        self.x1r1 = g1.x() 
        self.y1r1 = g1.y()
        self.x2r1 = g1.x() + g1.width()
        self.y2r1 = g1.y() + g1.height()

        g2 = self.radio_2.geometry()
        self.x1r2 = g2.x() 
        self.y1r2 = g2.y()
        self.x2r2 = g2.x() + g2.width()
        self.y2r2 = g2.y() + g2.height()

        g3 = self.radio_3.geometry()
        self.x1r3 = g3.x() 
        self.y1r3 = g3.y()
        self.x2r3 = g3.x() + g3.width()
        self.y2r3 = g3.y() + g3.height()

        super().resizeEvent(event)  

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):                      # +++ отслеживать, нажата ли мышь.
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        if (self.x1r1 < x < self.x2r1) and (self.y1r1 < y < self.y2r1):
            self.radio_1.click()
        elif (self.x1r2 < x < self.x2r2) and (self.y1r2 < y < self.y2r2):
            self.radio_2.click()
        elif (self.x1r3 < x < self.x2r3) and (self.y1r3 < y < self.y2r3):
            self.radio_3.click()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]